# get second and fourth saturday along with all sundays of the previous month in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have the following query which gives the second and fourth Saturdays of the previous month along with all the Sundays of the previous month:

```
SELECT to_char(NEXT_DAY(NEXT_DAY(NEXT_DAY(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC((SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1)) FROM DUAL), 'MONTH') - 1, 'SATURDAY'), 'SATURDAY'),'SATURDAY'),'SATURDAY'),'YYYYMMDD') SECOND_SATURDAY 
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(NEXT_DAY(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC((SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1)) FROM DUAL), 'MONTH') - 1, 'SATURDAY'),'SATURDAY'),'YYYYMMDD') SECOND_SATURDAY 
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
select distinct day_date from
(SELECT to_char(NEXT_DAY(LEVEL + TRUNC((SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1)) FROM DUAL), 'MONTH') - 1,'SUNDAY'),'YYYYMMDD') day_date
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC((SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1)) FROM DUAL), 'MONTH'), 1) - TRUNC((SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1)) FROM DUAL), 'MONTH'))
where substr(day_date,1,6) in (select to_char((SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1)) FROM DUAL),'YYYYMM') from dual)
```

But I feel there must be a simpler way to get the same result in oracle.Any help in this regard is welcome. My requirement for the date format is 'YYYYMMDD'.

Answer (score 0):

For instance like here:

```
with 
  t1 as (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -1) dt from dual),
  t2 as (
    select dt + level - 1 dt, to_char(dt + level - 1, 'dy', 'nls_date_language=english') dy
      from t1 connect by dt + level - 1 < trunc(sysdate, 'month'))
select to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd') dt, dy
  from (
    select dt, dy, sum(case when dy = 'sat' then 1 end) over (order by dt) sm from t2)
  where dy = 'sun' or (dy = 'sat' and sm in (2, 4))
```

Result:

```
DT       DY
-------- ---
20190203 sun
20190209 sat
20190210 sun
20190217 sun
20190223 sat
20190224 sun
```

I generated all days for previous month, assigned english day names, conditionally counted saturdays and showed only interesting dates.

---

**Edit:**

> This works but is there any way to get around the with clause since my
>   parent query is of the from: with x as ( .... where date in ("required
>   days") and ...) . So it presents a nested with situation.

Yes, you can convert it easily, for example like here:

```
select to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd') dt
  from (
    select dt, dn, rank() over (order by mod(dn, 6), dt) rnk
      from (
        select d + level - 1 dt, d + level - trunc(d + level - 1, 'iw') dn
          from (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -1) d from dual)
          connect by level <= add_months(d, 1) - d))
  where dn = 7 or (dn = 6 and rnk in (2, 4))
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=80568d8695a5019d4bc249557f6726d2)</sup>**

`with` clause made steps more readable. Now I also used day numbers and `mod()` for counting, just to show different approaches, but you can use whatever is clearer for you (day names, `sum` or `count` instead of `rank`).

Comment: This works but is there any way to get around the with clause since my parent query is of the from:  with x as ( .... where date in ("required days")  and ...) . So it presents a nested with situation

Answer (score 0):

**Edited because I misunderstood the question:**

I think you want something like the following:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(my_date, 'YYYYMMDD') AS my_formatted_date
  FROM (
    SELECT NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2))+7, 'SATURDAY') AS my_date
      FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2))+21, 'SATURDAY')
      FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2)), 'SUNDAY') + (LEVEL-1)*7
      FROM dual
   CONNECT BY NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2)), 'SUNDAY') + (LEVEL-1)*7 < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')
);
```

In the first part of the query I determine the last day of the previous month and then get the first Saturday that falls after at least one week after that date (the second Saturday of the month will be anywhere from the 8th to the 14th). Then I get the first Saturday falling at least three weeks after the last day of the previous month (the fourth Saturday will be anywhere from the 22nd to the 28th). Last, I loop over the Sundays of the previous month, starting from the first Sunday falling after the last day of the month previous to that (that is, two months ago). You could also use `NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1) - 1), 'SUNDAY')` instead of `NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2)), 'SUNDAY')`

```
MY_FORMA
--------
20190209
20190223
20190203
20190210
20190217
20190224

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Here the Saturdays are of current month . I guess I have to use (SYSDATE, -2) instead of (SYSDATE, -1)

Comment: Hi @katipra, I believe I misunderstood your question. Yes, use `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2)` instead of `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)` to get the needed answer.